# Postgre-Kit: Unable to complete code access to PostgreSQL DB

Tags: postgresql, vapor

**Goal:** To connect to a Postgre database and merely add simple data to a database table.

**Environment:**

```
// swift-tools-version:5.9
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Server_Todo",
    platforms: [
       .macOS(.v13)
    ],
    dependencies: [
        //  A server-side Swift web framework.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "4.77.1"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/multipart-kit.git", from: "4.5.4"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/postgres-kit.git", from: "2.12.2"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .executableTarget(
            name: "App",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "Vapor", package: "vapor"),
                .product(name: "MultipartKit", package: "multipart-kit"),
                .product(name: "PostgresKit", package: "postgres-kit"),
            ]
        ),
        .testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: [
            .target(name: "App"),
            .product(name: "XCTVapor", package: "vapor"),
        ])
    ]
)
```

**Problem:** postRealtor(): I keep getting deprecated code mixed with modern code where the modern code appears to be lacking basic support.  Fixing one problem creates another problem.

[image]

Most of the docs show deprecated code that doesn't sync with modern code.

I'm trying to create a very basic piece of workable code without the use of security or pooling.   That'll come later.

I'm left with the following incomplete code.
One big hassle is the conflict between the established *deprecated* **PostgresConfiguration** versus the modern S**QLPostgresConfiguration**.

```
import Logging
import MultipartKit
import PostgresKit
import Vapor

private enum Config {
    static let hostname = "localhost"
    static let port = 5432
    static let user = "Ric"
    static let password = "ThisSucks!"
    static let database = "db_realtor"
}

struct RealtorController: RouteCollection {
    func boot(routes: RoutesBuilder) throws {
        routes.get(use: getRealtor)

        let realtor = routes.grouped("realtor")
        realtor.post(use: postRealtor)
    }

    private func getRealtor(req _: Request) async throws -> String {
        "GET Realtor"
    }

    private func postRealtor(req: Request) async throws -> String {
        let logger = Logger(label: "postgres-logger")
        let result = try req.content.decode(Realtor.self)

        let config = SQLPostgresConfiguration(
            hostname: Config.hostname,
            port: Config.port,
            username: Config.user,
            password: Config.password,
            database: Config.database,
            tls: PostgresConnection.Configuration.TLS.disable
        )

        let connection = try await SQLPostgresConnection.connect(
            configuration: config,
            logger: logger
        )
        defer { try! await connection.close() }

        let sql = """
            INSERT INTO table_realtor (
                id, title, description, info
            ) VALUES (
                $1, $2, $3, $4
            )
        """

        let id = result.id ?? UUID()
        let title = result.title
        let description = result.description ?? nil
        let info = result.info ?? nil

        try await connection.execute(sql, [
            PostgresData(uuid: id),
            PostgresData(string: title),
            PostgresData(string: description!),
            PostgresData(string: info!),
        ])

        return "POST Realtor"
    }
}
```

The solution must be simple.  This is DB 101.  However the documentation is lacking.

Comment: What happens if you try 5.8 or 5.7?

Comment: If you're trying to connect to a DB without using Fluent at all (though I recommend it as you get everything like connection pooling etc for free, even if you only want to send raw queries), you're better off sticking to [PostgresNIO](https://github.com/vapor/postgres-nio)

Comment: Changing swift-tools-version doesn't have an effect.  Fluent was giving me grief over its 'ID' issue, refusing to acknowledge its presence nor generate one.  So I'm trying to reduce that layer of code.  I'll focus on PosgreNIO.   The solution shouldn't be complicated; so I'll grind on.